# mysql procedure with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I'm in my first databases class and I'm trying to write a conditional block for a mysql procedure.

This is the procedure:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_ascent(IN cid INT, IN pid INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE count_ascents INT;
    SET count_ascents = 0;
    SELECT COUNT(`cid`) INTO count_ascents FROM ascents WHERE `cid`=cid AND `pid`=pid;
    IF count_ascents < 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO ascents (`cid`, `pid`) VALUES (cid, pid);
        UPDATE climbers SET climbers.ascents = climbers.ascents + 1 WHERE climbers.id=cid;
        UPDATE problems SET problems.ascents = problems.ascents + 1 WHERE problems.id=pid;
    END IF;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

The goal of the procedure is to only perform the insert and updates if the (cid, pid) pair is not in the the ascents database. After testing, the program doesn't seem to go into the if block at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, you might want to consider using an [UPSERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)), instead of "select/if/insert".  For example, mySQL offers [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/).

Here, I suggest:

1. giving your parameters a DIFFERENT name than the column name, for example `iCid` and `iPid`, then
2. Typing `SELECT COUNT(cid) INTO count_ascents FROM ascents WHERE cid=iCid AND pid=iPid` and checking the result.

Comment: A shoot. That is a silly error...

If I wanted to change this into an UPSERT, then how would I conditionally update the other two tables? I always update if its not a duplicate key, but if it is then I don't update. Would I just update them twice if it is a duplicate key?

Comment: Also, thank you for looking at my code :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi - 1) In answer to your question, one could argue that you don't need either update.  Instead of storing "column ascents", simply "select (count)".  At which point the "two updates" issue is moot.  2) I'm curious: Q: Did you resolve you problem?  How?

Comment: I used your suggestion of different parameter names and kept it in a procedure. I figure it's a design issue to keep independent columns in the tables to track ascents vs. selecting count where climber.id = ascents.cid. Which is better in practice? It seems like there's greater potential for issues if I have to update 3 tables whenever I want to add a problem, but if you have a larger database of climbers it's costlier to do a select(count) for each of them.